# Emacs protection against simultaneous editing by same user

Tags: emacs

Emacs has elaborate [protection against simultaneous editing](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interlocking.html) by two different users.  If there a way to have that same facility for protecting against simultaneous editing by the *same* user?

With lots of windows and workspaces open, it's easy to reopen a file that you already have open somewhere else.  But because it does not detect a lock conflict when you open the file, you will only learn about the collision when you save.

Comment: Are you editing the file in two different copies of emacs?

Comment: Yes, on two different consoles.

Comment: I want basically the same behavior as vi with its swap files.

Answer (score 2):

If you edit a file you are visiting with another editor, GNU Emacs will warn you. If a programme updates a file that you are visiting, GNU Emacs will warn you.

If you revisit a file that is already in one of your buffers, then GNU Emacs will simply go to that buffer.

Practical examples;

- If you visit a file in GNU Emacs, and then edit and save that same file in nano, as soon as you try to edit in the Emacs buffer again (not just when you save), you will get a warning that the file has changed on disk and some options.
- If you visit a file and then, say, open a few more buffers and do other stuff (the usual thing), and then revisit that file later (eg. with C-x C-f or by hitting "enter" in dired) then GNU Emacs will not open a new buffer but will simply go back to the previous buffer you already have with that file.

Note: I'm using GNU Emacs 22 in gNewSense GNU/Linux

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I want to know about the conflict when I open the file, not when I save it.

Comment: @PeterEisentraut If both Emacs are just *viewing* the file, there's no need.  As soon as they *modify* the file, Emacs will warn (before saving, just modifying will trigger the warning).

Comment: @PeterEisentraut: I've confirmed Trey Jackson's answer - as soon as you try to edit the buffer, Emacs will prompt: `some_text_file.txt changed on disk; really edit the buffer? (y, n, r or C-h)`.

Comment: @Charles: I know that, but that is not the question.

Comment: Your question says "simultaneous *editing*.